# Javascript src attribute vs. document.write vs. insertBefore

Tags: javascript, include

What are the pros and cons of the 3 popular methods for including 3rd party js? Why do respected companies (jQuery, Google, Amazon) use different methods? In what situations does it make more sense to use each of these methods?

**Option 1 (jQuery - src attribute):**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Option 2 (GA - insertBefore):**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || []; 
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-WHATEVS']);
        (function() { 
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true; 
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js'; 
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s); 
        })();
</script>
```

**Option 3 (Amazon - doc.write):**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(unescape('%3Cscript type="text/javascript" src="'+document.location.protocol+'//abc.cloudfront.net/pages/scripts/0000/xxx.js"%3E%3C%2Fscript%3E'))
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1** is synchronous inclusion.  That javascript will be read, parsed and executed before any following javascript.

**Option 2** is asynchronous inclusion.  It is loaded asychronously and has no guaranteed timing vs. other scripts in the page.  This has the advantage that the rest of the page does not wait for it to load or execute, but the disadvantage that anything trying to use it has to know when it has been successfully loaded.  The specific example you show for option 2 is for Google Analytics which is self contained and not dependent upon anything else in the page so it makes perfect sense to be asynchronous and not make anything else on the page wait for it to load.

**Option 3** is still synchronous (like option 1), but obfuscates the inclusion of the script a little bit which fools some filters that may be trying to filter a specific script.  It also allows you to use your own javascript to decide what scripts to include or where to include them from, but to have them included synchronously.  You can also use your own javascript to manipulate the protocol (http/https) or domain if there's any reason to do that based on the loading page.

Comment: Well I thought it was a good answer. +1. @user1091283
- Note that the specific Option 2 example from the question happens to be for Google Analytics, which means (from the user's point of view) it doesn't matter if it loads at all so doing it async makes sense. And Option 3 allows you to add some extra logic to conditionally include scripts while still keeping them synchronous.

Comment: @jfriend00 - your answer looks good to me (not sure who down voted)... i'm just gonna hang on a little longer to allow others to contribute. thx!

Comment: @nnnnnn - I incorporated your comments into the answer.

Comment: I think that some, hopefully *newer*, users don't understand what the toggles do. I've seen Matt Ball get a drive-by several times on perfectly good answers, sometimes more than once on the same answer. I would upvote too, but I am out of votes for another hour. `+1`

Comment: Yep 1 standard synchronous hard coded way.  2 and 3 are protocol agnostic (http vs https).  2 is optimized to be asynchronously downloaded, but note that it also points to 2 different URLS based on the protocol.  This is no doubt for performance on Google's side. And option 3 is simply different a way to include the script regardless of the protocol (http vs https) with the above mentioned benefits

Comment: I was hoping to understand the pros/cons of (Option 1) using a script tag, (Option 2) adding a script tag via `Node.insertBefore`, and (Option 3) adding a script tag via `document.write`.  Instead your answer focuses mostly on the fact that Option 2 includes `async` and Option 3 obfuscates the script tag.  But both Options 1 and 3 could be modified to use `async` on the script tag, could they not?  Is there any other difference in the methodologies if that were done?  (Obfuscation in Option 3 aside.)

Comment: @CarlG - Since this is a 6+ year old question and seemed to answer what the OP was interested in, it might be best if you ask a new question that is focused on exactly what you want to know.  After posting, you can address a comment to me and I'll take a look.

Comment: This question may be over 6 years old, but Google directs here for queries like "document.write vs. insertBefore".  Thanks for offering to look at another question, I'll comment if I write the question you requested.